# Condition in WHERE clause

Tags: sql, where-clause

I'm trying to change my WHERE clause based on the value of one column of my table.
My tables are:

**server_updates**

```
k1ID        updID
----------- -----------
```

**server_updates_cat**

```
sucID        updID       catID       selectChildren   includeNullType
-----------  ----------- ----------- ---------------- --------------
```

**server_updates_types**

```
sucID       typeID
----------- -----------
```

And here's what I'm doing:

```
DECLARE @k1_catID INT
DECLARE @k4_type INT

SET @k1_catID = 30
SET @k4_type = 1

SELECT suc.sucID, suc.updID FROM server_updates su
INNER JOIN server_updates_cat suc ON suc.updID = su.updID

WHERE
includeNullType = 0
    AND suc.catID = @k1_catID
    AND selectChildren = 1
    AND @k4_type IN (SELECT typeID FROM server_updates_types sut WHERE sut.sucID = suc.sucID)
OR
includeNullType = 1 
    AND KSUC.catID = @k1_catID
    AND selectChildren = 1
    AND (@k4_type IN (SELECT typeID FROM server_updates_types sut WHERE sut.sucID = suc.sucID) OR @k4_type IS NULL)
```

I would like to not have to repeat all conditions either `includeNullType = 0` or `includeNullType = 1`, but change the only thing I really need to change, which is:

`@k4_type IN (SELECT typeID FROM server_updates_types sut WHERE sut.sucID = suc.sucID)`

Is there another way of doing that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
WHERE suc.catID = @k1_catID
AND selectChildren = 1
AND (
(includeNullType = 0   
AND @k4_type IN (SELECT typeID FROM server_updates_types sut WHERE sut.sucID = suc.sucID))
OR
(includeNullType = 1 
    AND (@k4_type IN (SELECT typeID FROM server_updates_types sut WHERE sut.sucID = suc.sucID) OR @k4_type IS NULL))
)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can rearrange the ANDs and ORs. Simplifying:

```
includeNull = 0 AND LONG_CONDITION
OR
includeNull = 1 AND (LONG_CONDITION OR COND2)
```

If includeNull can only be 0 or 1, this is logically equivalent to

```
LONG_CONDITION OR (includeNull = 1 AND COND2)
```